# Filtering, sorting multiple tables with Elide.io

Tags: java, spring-boot, elide

I am using Java (11), Spring Boot (2.7) and [Elide (6.1)](https://elide.io/). I want to create a GET endpoint (`/table3data`) which combines data from three different tables - `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`. I need this endpoint to provide such common Elide API features as filtering, sorting, pagination.

Specifically, I need to filter by `table1Id` (one or several comma-separated `table1Id`s) and by `date` (both found in `Table3`) - that could also include filtering by two `date`s. `table1Id` is also `refId` in `Table1`.

Normally, when fetching data from an endpoint which contains one table data, such as only `Table1` (`/table1`), operations such as filtering and sorting will work fine.

`Table3` has many-to-one relationships with both `Table1` and `Table2`. `Table1` and `Table2` are not connected with each other.

```java
@Include
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "my_entity")
@CreatePermission(expression = "deny all")
@DeletePermission(expression = "deny all")
@UpdatePermission(expression = "deny all")
public class Table1 {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
  private Long id;
  private String type;
  private String status;
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String refId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Table3> table3 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Include
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "my_entity")
@CreatePermission(expression = "deny all")
@DeletePermission(expression = "deny all")
@UpdatePermission(expression = "deny all")
public class Table2 {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String reference;
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String refId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Table3> table3 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Include
@Entity
@Table(name = "table3")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "my_entity")
@CreatePermission(expression = "deny all")
@DeletePermission(expression = "deny all")
@UpdatePermission(expression = "deny all")
public class Table3 {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "table1_id", referencedColumnName = "refId")
  private Table1 table1;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private Date date;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "table2_id", referencedColumnName = "refId")
  private Table2 table2;
}
```

I am using Repositories:

```java
public interface Table1Repository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Table1, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Table1> {
}
```

```java
public interface Table2Repository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Table2, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Table2> {
}
```

```java
public interface Table3Repository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Table3, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Table3> {
}
```

So far I have implemented a `Table3DTO` entity which contains all of the properties from the three tables (`id`, `type`, `status`, `name`, `reference`, `amount`, `date`, `table1Id`, `table2Id`).

Then I have a `Table3Service` class, which combines the data in the correct way (it has a method `getAllTable3Data()` which returns a `List<Table3DTO>`).

Then I have a `Table3Response` which is the wrapper for `Table3ResponseData`. `Table3ResponseData` creates the inner structure of the response.

Lastly I have a `Table3Controller`, which has the `/table3data` implemented and returns the `Table3Response`.

However, even though I get the necessary data, I still need to implement filtering, sorting and other operations myself. Usually these would be provided by Elide.
I prefer not to use the current solution, that's why I am not including the code.

Is there a better way to implement this with Elide, so that I wouldn't have to implement these operations myself, as that is not only time-consuming, but also can get error-prone?

Answer (score 2):

In general a query using sparse fields and compound documents should meet your query requirements.

For instance a query to include specific fields of related tables

`/book?include=authors&fields[book]=title,authors&fields[author]=name`

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing Swagger documentation() for Elide endpoints it helps a lot with filtring and sorting .

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.yahoo.elide</groupId>
                <artifactId>elide-swagger</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

using the swagger filds will help you avoid syntax error .

[image]